# Changing width of footer for Section not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Hey i try to change the width of my footer for sections with:

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{

UIView *viewFooter = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 44)];

[viewFooter setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

return viewFooter;
}
```

But the footer is always as width as the tableview (320.0f).....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the table view will always make the section head the full width of the table.

The easiest solution is to make your "real" footer a subview of the actual footer view.

Something like this:

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    UIView *mainFooter = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];

    UIView *viewFooter = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 44)];
    [viewFooter setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    viewFooter.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingMaskFlexibleWidth;
    [mainFooter addSubview:viewFooter];

    return mainFooter;
}

// You must implement this when you implement viewForFooterInSection
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 44;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a container around your desired footer custom view if it will have a different size than the actual tableview. This should work:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    UIView *viewFooter = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 44)];
    [viewFooter setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];


    // Create a footer container that has a fixed width
    // but in which you can adjust subviews frame as you want.
    //
    UIView *footerContainer = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 320, 44)];
    [footerContainer addSubview:viewFooter];

    return footerContainer;
}
```